# Rails render_to_string "undefined method" for custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6...

I have a custom helper that works fine when I point a browser to the view. But I use this same view elsewhere to generate a PDF (using render_to_string) that gets attached to an email. In that context, I get an `undefined method` error.

Here's the app/views/submissions/show.slim (it's a React SPA):

```
= javascript_tag do
  | var rawForm =  #{raw(@submission.frm.to_json)}

= pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag 'shower'
= pdf_javascript_pack_tag 'shower'
```

Here's the app/helpers/pdf_helper.rb

```
module PdfHelper
  def pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag(source)
    if running_in_development?
      options = { media: "all" }
      wds = Webpacker.dev_server
      options[:host] = "#{wds.host}:#{wds.port}" unless show_as_html?
      stylesheet_pack_tag(source, options)
    else
      wicked_pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag(source)
    end
  end

  def pdf_javascript_pack_tag(source)
    if running_in_development?
      options = {}
      wds = Webpacker.dev_server
      options[:host] = "#{wds.host}:#{wds.port}" unless show_as_html?
      javascript_pack_tag(source, options)
    else
      wicked_pdf_javascript_pack_tag(source)
    end
  end

  def show_as_html?
    params[:debug].present?
  end

end
```

(This helper shims an issue with the Wicked PDF gem.)

Here's app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb

```
class NotificationsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_submission(submission, email)
    @submission = submission
    @frm = submission.frm
    attachments["submission-#{submission.id}.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      render_to_string(
        'submissions/show',
        layout: 'pdf',
        locals: {:@submission => submission}
      )
    )
    mail to: email
  end
end
```

When the mailer tries to send the email I see this error in the logs:

```
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [f8ce8ecc-2ae5-447d-85f0-bd46bf3c8b20]   Rendered submissions/show.slim within layouts/pdf (Duration: 39.5ms | Allocations: 12324)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [f8ce8ecc-2ae5-447d-85f0-bd46bf3c8b20] NotificationsMailer#new_submission: processed outbound mail in 444.2ms
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [f8ce8ecc-2ae5-447d-85f0-bd46bf3c8b20] Error performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: f8ce8ecc-2ae5-447d-85f0-bd46bf3c8b20) from Async(mailers) in 444.67ms: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pdf_javascript_pack_tag' for #<#<Class:0x00007f8c728defb8>:0x00007f8c728dcc68>):
/Users/emerson/Code/consent/app/views/submissions/show.slim:6:in `_app_views_submissions_show_slim__295365913496948297_70120585776840'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`render_to_string` is the method of `ActionController` class. Try the below to make use of the method `render_to_string` outside of the controllers(which inherited from the ActionController).

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string('submissions/show',
        layout: 'pdf',
        locals: {:@submission => submission})
```

Comment: New error:
```
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [74cfaa5c-d6e7-4474-9ade-1f0b0f3bdb3b] Error performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: 74cfaa5c-d6e7-4474-9ade-1f0b0f3bdb3b) from Async(mailers) in 1024.51ms: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass):
/Users/emerson/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:1095:in `params'
/Users/emerson/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionview-6.0.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb:16:in `params'
```

Comment: Can you share the view file for the mailer?